# Exception could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I got a web service method

```
@Override
@GET
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void getInfo(HttpServletRequest req) {

}
```

with return type void, I can't change the return type because this method is comming from an interface and I want to send ok response from the method, for that I have used  **@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)**, but when I am requsting the service I am getting:

```
Exception could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
```

any solution is appreciated.

Comment: Try taking the `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT** instead of **HttpStatus.OK**?

A 200 (OK) response for a GET request implies an entity corresponding to the requested resource is to be returned on the response while 204 (NoContent) means there is no need to return an entity-body.

See [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for a definition of each response code.